# In SQL server is a check constraint applied before or after a default constraint on insert?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, default-value, check-constraints

As per the title: In SQL server is a check constraint applied before or after a default constraint on insert?

So taking the following table (Unnecessary columns omitted for brevity)...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CountryCode] [varchar](5) NULL CONSTRAINT [CK_Customer_DefaultCountryCode]  DEFAULT ([app].[GetUnknownCountryIsoCountryCode]()),
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

...Which also has the following check constraint...

```
ALTER TABLE [admin].[Customer]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_CustomerHasCountryWhenIntercompanyBusinessModel] 
    CHECK  (
        ([app].[BusinessModelMustHaveCountry]([BusinessModelId]) = (1) AND [app].[CheckCountryCodeExists]([CountryCode]) = (1) OR 
        [app].[BusinessModelMustHaveCountry]([BusinessModelId]) <> (1))
    )
GO
```

... will the default constraint be applied and populate the default value before the check constraint is applied?

Comment: I would assume the default is applied first - it'll decide what to try insert before trying to insert it and verifying the check constraint. It should be easy to test the behaviour. One thing to note: default constraints do not fire if a NULL value is inserted, even for `NOT NULL` columns, and some people expect them to.

Comment: @DavidSpillett +1 for the extra information about NULL inserts in NOT NULL columns. I'd did not know that - Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The check constraint is applied after.

You can see this from the fact that the following succeeds.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT DEFAULT 1 CHECK (X = 1)); 

INSERT @T DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Also the  execution plan shows that the assert operator operates on the values output from the table insert operator so is checking the values that were actually inserted.

[image]